# Can I Update an npm Package to a Newer Version Without Deleting package-lock.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

In my package.json, there is an npm package specified as `^1.6.0.`

Two weeks ago, when I initially installed the package, it was at version `1.7.0`, which is the version currently residing in my node_modules directory.

Now, the package has been updated to version `1.8.0`.

When I run `npm install` again, it continues to install version 1.7.0.

Is there a way to instruct npm to install version `1.8.0` without having to delete the `package-lock.json` file?

The idea is to still using the version packages from package-lock but those specific package should be 1.8.0 version but still having `^1.6.0` in `package.json`

Comment: I guess, that you can change the version in `package.json` directly to `1.8.0`

Comment: You can use `npm-check-updates`

Comment: If you need version 1.8.0 then you need to change the version in `package.json`. If you don't need version 1.8.0, then what's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm update [package]` will do what you want as long as it is a patch or minor version bump.